# MySQL Get first and last day of multiple records

Tags: mysql, aggregate

I have a table [HC_RSPI_data](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1331f/17):

```
| RADIO_TYPE |   HOP | TOWARDS | RSPI |       TP_NAME |          DATE_TIME_END | TIME_LENGTH | RLTM_min | RLTM_max |
|------------|-------|---------|------|---------------|------------------------|-------------|----------|----------|
| FlexiMetro | H3376 | RAPSANI | RSPI | ODU 1 Radio 1 | June, 08 2015 00:00:00 |       86400 |       65 |       37 |
| FlexiMetro | H3376 | RAPSANI | RSPI | ODU 1 Radio 1 | June, 09 2015 00:00:00 |       86400 |       70 |       37 |
| FlexiMetro | H3376 | RAPSANI | RSPI | ODU 1 Radio 1 | June, 08 2015 00:00:00 |       86400 |       65 |       37 |
| FlexiMetro | H3376 | RAPSANI | RSPI | ODU 2 Radio 2 | June, 10 2015 00:00:00 |       86400 |       74 |       47 |
| FlexiMetro | H3376 | RAPSANI | RSPI | ODU 2 Radio 2 | June, 09 2015 00:00:00 |       86400 |       74 |       47 |
| FlexiMetro | H3376 | RAPSANI | RSPI | ODU 2 Radio 2 | June, 08 2015 00:00:00 |       86400 |       74 |       47 |
```

And i want to get the records with the first and last day like:

```
| RADIO_TYPE |   HOP | TOWARDS | RSPI |       TP_NAME |          DATE_TIME_END | TIME_LENGTH | RLTM_min | RLTM_max |
|------------|-------|---------|------|---------------|------------------------|-------------|----------|----------|
| FlexiMetro | H3376 | RAPSANI | RSPI | ODU 1 Radio 1 | June, 08 2015 00:00:00 |       86400 |       65 |       37 |
| FlexiMetro | H3376 | RAPSANI | RSPI | ODU 1 Radio 1 | June, 10 2015 00:00:00 |       86400 |       70 |       37 |

| FlexiMetro | H3376 | RAPSANI | RSPI | ODU 2 Radio 2 | June, 08 2015 00:00:00 |       86400 |       74 |       47 |
| FlexiMetro | H3376 | RAPSANI | RSPI | ODU 2 Radio 2 | June, 10 2015 00:00:00 |       86400 |       74 |       47 |
```

OR

One record with  2 fileds Start date and End date like:
min(DATE_TIME_END) as Start date and  max(DATE_TIME_END) as End date

How can i achieve this?
I was trying something like this

```
SELECT DISTINCT rssi.* 
FROM HC_RSPI_data as rssi
INNER JOIN HC_RSPI_data as j
on  rssi.RADIO_TYPE     =   j.RADIO_TYPE     
and rssi.HOP            =   j.HOP            
and rssi.TOWARDS        =   j.TOWARDS        
and rssi.RSPI           =   j.RSPI           
and rssi.TP_NAME        =   j.TP_NAME
and rssi.DATE_TIME_END = j.DATE_TIME_END or j.DATE_TIME_END = DATE_ADD(rssi.DATE_TIME_END, INTERVAL 6 DAY)
```

Any ideas?

Thank you.

Comment: What's the reason for the `DATE_ADD(..., INTERVAL 6 DAY)` in the code?

Comment: To @oNare: If you remove those 3 columns from the `SELECT` list, your query would be fine (but I'm not sure if it's an answer that would satisfy the question.)

Comment: You need to use GROUP BY on columns which identify one resulting row and then select max() and min() as you described it. It seems your table could use some normalization, currently all those text fields seem to be repeated many times.